# Flyway scripts not executing if class loaded via classloader

Tags: spring-mvc, database-migration, flyway

I have a project and a subproject there are apis in sub project which are accessed via main project.

First I compile the subproject into jar along with dependencies.

Next I load the jar using url classloaders

Next from main project using reflection I consume the apis in subproject.

I have configured flyway in the sub project and added the sql scripts in subproject. Flyway migration is done using an api call. Now when I hit the api directly in sub project, flyway scripts are executed. If I load the class via classloaders and then hit the api from main project the scripts are not executed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hit the api". How do you observe the "scripts are not executed" behavior? Are you getting any error, or how else do you know they are not executed? Can you give some more details, or show a piece of code that you think is failing?

Comment: Flyway loads migrations using the classloader you give it. My guess without seeing sample code is that you are providing it the wrong classloader to 'see' the migrations.